# Running multiple application using Remote App in Windows

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have successfully achieved how to execute an remote application on a Windows 7 ultimate machine. I used this link: [http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20210117115603/http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2009/12/18/137048.aspx)

My question is Can I run two different applications simultaneously from the remote machine using Remote app?
The blog suggests that to provide the path of the executable like following way in the RDP config file:

```
remoteapplicationprogram:s:C:\Windows\programm.exe
```

I am able to run single application with no problems, but I wonder if I can run two different applications. PS: I am able to run these two different application individually. I tried something like this but no success:

```
remoteapplicationprogram:s:C:\Windows\programm1.exe
remoteapplicationprogram:s:C:\Windows\programm2.exe
```

But in this case only the `programm1.exe` executes.

**Simplified problem:** Lets simply the problem, how can I create a RDP config file so that when I execute it, it executes the notepad as well as the calculator on the remote machine? I know how to execute one app at a time. But I don't know how to execute multiple apps at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from one of my coworkers:

Instead of specifying multiple programs in the RDP file, specify a batch file that contains

```
start "" c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe
start "" c:\windows\system32\calc.exe
```

When you connect the batch file will run and start both programs.

Comment: Well this is a clever solution. I'll test this and let you know if it worked.

Comment: This way will only start a cmd on remote server, you wont see the application interface

Comment: @RootLoop I see the application interface...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run multiple applications and executables but each executable has to be published for it to run.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean by publish. Please provide the details. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Perhaps this will help?  You may need to expand on your environment, server OS, etc if this doesn't help - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2345.publish-a-remoteapp-application-on-remote-desktop-service.aspx

Comment: Thanks, That works only for a Server machine. In my case I have a Windows 7 ultimate. :(